# Process.Start opens multiple tabs

Tags: c#

I'm using the following code to create a file from a byte array and then opening that file using the default application:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), docName);
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, docBytArray);
Process.Start(filePath);
```

This particular file is a PDF and the associated app is Microsoft Edge. The file is opened correctly, however Edge creates 4 or 5 tabs for the same file.

Is this a problem of `Process.Start` or of `Edge`?

Comment: Does this happen if you double click the file from the shell?  Perhaps Edge is restoring tabs when it starts.

Comment: @AlexK. Good point. Double-click from the temp folder opens 1 tab as expected. Edge is not restoring tabs as I'm closing all of them before close it.

Comment: If you try `start "" "C:\some\path\to\a.pdf"` from `cmd`, same behaviour?

Comment: @spender No. It opens just 1 tab as well.

Comment: When I keep Edge open with just 1 empty tab and then execute the above code, only 1 tab is created for the file. When Edge is closed, it opens multiple tabs.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, and it always open only one tab on my pc.